# I am making the app in sharepoint, however i am not able to find the api in the sharepoint to resolve the issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-online

The API that I need from the sharePoint is mention below:-

1. How to get all groups a user is a member of
2. Inside library permissions we have a setting to disable library data from appearing in Search, Below mention is the screenshot for which I am looking the api.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qznKu.png)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the chosen technology, but generally:

1. SPUser object have the Groups property.

In CSOM:

> ```
> var ctx = new ClientContext(url);
> var user = ctx.Site.RootWeb.EnsureUser(userName);
> ctx.Load(user.Groups);
> ctx.ExecuteQuery();
> ```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.groups?view=sharepoint-server#microsoft-sharepoint-spuser-groups

2. Use "NoCrawl" property from a SPList object.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.nocrawl?view=sharepoint-server#microsoft-sharepoint-splist-nocrawl

Comment: Thank's for sharing the link's however currently I am using the node JS as backend , I am able to find out the all groups a user is a member of API, however Not able to find  the library permissions setting, the link mentioned is based on C#. Does the sharepoint api vary from account to account as I do have the education account currently. It will be a great help for me if you can help me with the api of the shared screenshot.